# Function to find the factors of a negative number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a function that will find the factors for a negative number and output them to a list. How would I do that? I can get my function to do positive numbers (see below) but not negative ones.

```
#Finds factors for A and C
def factorspos(x):
    factorspos = [1,-6];
    print("The factors of",x,"are:")
    for i in range(1, x + 1):
        if x % i == 0:
            factorspos.append(i)
            print(i)
```

I tried changing the values that the loop counts from so it would count from the number chosen to 1 (Code below) but still yielded no results :(

```
#Finds factors for A and C
def factorspos(x):
    factorspos = [int(-6),1];
    print("The factors of",x,"are:")
    for i in range(int(-6), x + 1):
        if x % i == 0:
            factorspos.append(i)
            print(i)
```

I have changed Cco to a fixed number.

```
#Finds factors for A and C
def factorspos(x):
    Cco = -6
    factorspos = [int(Cco),1];
    print("The factors of",x,"are:")
    for i in range(int(Cco), x + 1):
        if x % i == 0:
            factorspos.append(i)
            print(i)
            return factorspos
```

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. Do you have a question?

Comment: @Sepy13: what is the value of `Cco` ? and you really shouldn't call your "return value" the same way as your function. This is not visual basic (so you actually have to _return_ something or your function won't work.

Comment: @Sepy13: read this: you _have_ to return `factorpos`

Comment: @Sepy13: return your result _after_ your loop has completed :) And you did _not_ change `Cco` by a fixed number. Still no-go to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Positive and negative numbers have exactly the same factors (with a slightly different sign pattern in the products).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def factorspos(x):
    x = int(x)
    factorspos = []
    print("The factors of",x,"are:")
    if x > 0: # if input is postive
        for i in range(1,x+1):
            if x % i == 0:
                factorspos.append(i)
                print(i)
        return factorspos
    elif x < 0: #if input is negative
        for i in range(x,0):
            if x % i == 0:
                factorspos.append(i)
                print(i)
        return factorspos


print(factorspos(12))   #outputs [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12]
print(factorspos(-12))  #outputs [-12, -6, -4, -3, -2, -1]
```

You were actually really close to fixing your issue. I took the liberty of adding an extra function to what you had. Basically I added a condiction checker to see if the input `x` is positive or negative, the the function did two different things. What they do was what you provided, but cleaned up.

Things to note `range()` starts from one the first number inclusive, and ends one number short of the second parameter. `range(1,10)` will give you 1 to 9. So that's why if you look, the negative section the range goes from x to 0 since that will say x to -1. In the positive section it will go from 1 to x+1 since +1 insures we include our input. The rest you know about since, well you wrote it; if not feel free to ask questions.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry if I was a little nooby :)

Comment: @Sepy13 Everyone has to start out, being a noob is not an issue. Just make sure you do yourself a favor and research first, then ask a complete answer which includes your code, what you've tried, what your question/issue is and desire input and output. That way people can help you faster and easier.